# evilgrade / netcat worked (once) and then never worked again

Tags: dns, netcat

So in a controlled environment I used evilgrade, a payload I had created, etter, and then netcat to do a mitm to get my target device to install my created payload as an "update" and it worked. I got my target device to successfully do this and so I began writing a python script to automate this process rather than memorize the commands and now it does not work. As stated before everything worked flawlessly the first time through, but after I had established a connection to the target device, I cannot replicate it. I have tried uninstalling/purging all of the applications (except ettercap) and doing a fresh install as well as returning all config files like etter.dns and etter.conf to their defaults before trying to replicate.

The evilgrade CLI shows this:

start
evilgrade>
[3/5/2017:9:40:33] - [WEBSERVER] - Webserver ready. Waiting for connections ...

evilgrade>
[3/5/2017:9:40:33] - [DNSSERVER] - DNS Server Ready. Waiting for Connections ...

evilgrade>

The netcat CLI shows this:

root@oxYMmCIZ:~# nc -l -p 444 -v
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 444)

The first time netcat ran I saw what looked like something encrypted going across the CLI (I assume showing that traffic was indeed coming through) but I did not use -v that time so I did not see anything but the squares.

This is my first questions here and I feel like I should state that I am self taught so if I misuse any terms feel free to let me know. I know how to make stuff work, not explain it by the books' terms :)